# Convert polar coordinates to specific angle range

Tags: trigonometry

I shamefully admit that my trig-skill have rusted.

I have a point on the uniform circle by $\sin(\alpha) = x$ and $\cos(\alpha) = y$ coordinate.

For example: $\alpha = 0 \to (0,1)^T$

The angle is in range $[-\pi,\pi]$

Clockwise is the positive direction
eg: $\alpha = \pi/2 \to (1,0)^T$.

Given an $(x,y)$ ordered pair, how do I get the angle ?

Comment: Hint: the tangent function. Draw a picture of the situation and contemplate on what is the meaning of taking the tangent of the angle.

Comment: You didn't say why you want to do the computation, but if it's part of a computer program, you might want to check out the atan2 function, which is part of the math library for most programming languages.

Comment: What is the context in which you are doing this? If it's just one or two examples you have to work through "by hand" with a calculator, you can use the regular arc tangent with 180-degree corrections for the times when it is obviously wrong. But if you are doing this in software then you might be better off with the atan2(y,x) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual convention is $$\begin{cases}x=\cos\theta,\\ y=\sin\theta\end{cases}$$ so we can make the connection with $$\alpha=\dfrac\pi2-\theta.$$

Then

$$\frac yx=\tan\theta=\cot\alpha$$

and

$$\theta=\arctan\frac yx,\alpha=\arctan\frac xy.$$

Anyway, to retrieve an angle on the four quadrants, you need to consider the signs. If $y<0$, add $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the inverse tangent function. Take both lengths and divide x by y.

So,$\frac{sin{(x)}}{cos{(x)}}^{-1}$

$tan^{-1}(n)=\angle{a}$, where “n” is the result of $\frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}$

Comment: Assuming your $a$ denotes $\alpha$, the notation $\angle{a}$ is wrong. Indeed this would denote the argument of the complex number $a$, trivially $0$ as $a$ is a real angle.